# does Barebox bootloader works on cortex m4?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, boot-loader, arm, uclinux

I want to boot uCLinux on the stm32f4 but I don't have enough knowledge about Barebox. is it possible to port Barebox for cortex m4? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. but the barebox community is working on it to bring barebox to cortex m devices too. I suggest you to use u-boot for now because it supports many cortex m socs (m3, m4 and m7).

---

you can easily port barebox for any cortex m mcu. you can use u-boot drivers to port them to barebox.

you must have a deep knowledge about linux/u-boot driver model.